# My greasepaint pen has been drawing like a hole inch away from where my cursor is does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: grease-pencil

I was Following Worthy Kids 2d animation tutorial on youtube. I got done with the art board section. It came to the line art portion so I made a new file with just the first shots frames. I changed the settings from draw to object and added a new blank grease pencil.

When I went to make a line it was an inch away from where I drew it. I restarted my computer and recallibrated my tablet pen. I messed around with all the pencil settings and it had nothing to do with my tablet pen because when I used my mouse and finger to draw a line it was still an inch or more away from where I made contact.

I went to the original savefile the story boards to remake the first shot file. And even with the new file when I add the new grease pencil it is offset. It wasn't offset before I made the new grease pencil but after. I'm new to Blender.